# SQL statement to update duplicate record keeping 1 record unchanged

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to get the solution for this condition. I have a table containing records, there is a field sku, in this record i have sku's appearing multiple times. Table structure is like this rid|id|sku|name

if any sku is available on table multiple times the record looks like this

```
rid  id  sku     name
---  --  ------  --------------

1    3   rs-123  test product

2    3   rs-123  test product

3    4   rs-125  test product 2

4    4   rs-125  test product 2

5    4   rs-125  test product 2

6    6   rs-126  test product 3
```

What I need is to update the table with duplicate records keeping first record unchanged (N-1). So for example I need to run SQL statement which update only duplicate records, so if first record is updated it will look like this

```
rid  id  sku     name
---  --  ------  --------------
1    3   rs-123  test product
2    3   updated  updated
```

I was trying to achieve something with this SQL statement but it is not working

```
WITH duplicates AS (
  SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rid) AS duplicate_id,
*
FROM
test
)

UPDATE
  duplicates
SET
  sku = updated
WHERE
  duplicate_id > 1
```

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have tagged the question as `MYSQL`, but seem to run analytics from `SQL Server` in your question e.g. `ROW_NUMBER()`, so check my update for sql server as well.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question, you have articulated well with your sample table schema and with a query you tried out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may give it a try with a variable:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fac10/2)

```
set @sku:='';

select a.rid, a.id, 
@sku:= (case when @sku<>a.sku
        then a.sku else 'updated'
        end) as skus, @sku:=a.sku, a.name
from skus a
;

| RID | ID |    SKUS | @SKU:=A.SKU |           NAME |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  3 |  rs-123 |      rs-123 |   test product |
|   2 |  3 | updated |      rs-123 |   test product |
|   3 |  4 |  rs-125 |      rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | updated |      rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   5 |  4 | updated |      rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   6 |  6 |  rs-126 |      rs-126 | test product 3 |
```

For updating:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO for UPDATING](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecb91/1)

```
set @sku:='';

UPDATE
  skus a
  join 
  (select a.rid, a.id, 
@sku:= (case when @sku<>a.sku
        then a.sku else 'updated'
        end) as skus, @sku:=a.sku, a.name
from skus a) b
  on a.rid = b.rid
SET
  a.sku = 'up_again'
WHERE
  b.skus = 'updated'
;

| RID | ID |      SKU |           NAME |
----------------------------------------
|   1 |  3 |   rs-123 |   test product |
|   2 |  3 | up_again |   test product |
|   3 |  4 |   rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | up_again | test product 2 |
|   5 |  4 | up_again | test product 2 |
|   6 |  6 |   rs-126 | test product 3 |
```

Here is another using `Joins`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddf47/2

```
update skus a
join skus b
on a.rid = b.rid +1
set a.sku = 'updated'
where a.sku = b.sku
;


| RID | ID |     SKU |           NAME |
---------------------------------------
|   1 |  3 |  rs-123 |   test product |
|   2 |  3 | updated |   test product |
|   3 |  4 |  rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | updated | test product 2 |
|   5 |  4 | updated | test product 2 |
|   6 |  6 |  rs-126 | test product 3 |
```

**To update both sku and name:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97f4f/1

```
update skus a
join skus b
on a.rid = b.rid +1
set a.sku = 'updated', a.name = 'new_name'
where a.sku = b.sku
;

| RID | ID |     SKU |           NAME |
---------------------------------------
|   1 |  3 |  rs-123 |   test product |
|   2 |  3 | updated |       new_name |
|   3 |  4 |  rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | updated |       new_name |
|   5 |  4 | updated |       new_name |
|   6 |  6 |  rs-126 | test product 3 |
```

---

### LOOKING AT OP'S QUESTION having used ROW_NUMBER() IN SQL SERVER

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/355c4/2

```
update a 
set a.sku = 'updated', a.name = 'new_name'
from skus a
join (Select rid, id, row_number() over (
  partition by id order by rid asc) rank
from skus) b
on a.rid = b.rid
where b.rank > 1
;

| RID | ID |     SKU |           NAME |
---------------------------------------
|   1 |  3 |  rs-123 |   test product |
|   2 |  3 | updated |       new_name |
|   3 |  4 |  rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | updated |       new_name |
|   5 |  4 | updated |       new_name |
|   6 |  6 |  rs-126 | test product 3 |
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit, why we need to have one additional column after update @SKU:=A.SKU

Comment: `@sku:=a.sku` is used to set the value for `@sku` variable. At the beginning the value of the varialbe is none. So it is purposely and meant to not equal to the sku that you have in the table. But from second onwards, `@sku` variable must have the first value to match if the next is the same. `=)` See here why it's important http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b0d5/1

Comment: Got your point, in case1 we can only update SKUS, what if we need to update NAME and SKUS both?

Comment: @Khureem take a look at another solution that is much simpler with `joins` :D you can update both `sku` and `name` as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97f4f/1 However do notice that the `join` solution is mainly depending on your `RID`, assuming it's unique for each record and squentially incrementing.

Comment: Awesome brother it worked perfectly fine, love you :) highly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  sku = 'updatedSKU'
WHERE rid IN
(
  SELECT
    rid
  FROM
  (
    SELECT rid,
        @rn := IF(@sku != sku, 1, @rn + 1) rn,
        @sku:=sku
     FROM test,
        (SELECT @rn:=0, @sku := NULL) r
  ) s
  WHERE rn > 1
);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/647f6/1)**

or this:

```
UPDATE
   test t
   JOIN
     (
       SELECT rid,
           CASE WHEN @sku != sku THEN @rn := 1 ELSE @rn := @rn + 1 END rn,
           @sku:=sku
        FROM test,
          (SELECT @rn:=0, @sku := NULL) r
     ) s
  ON t.rid = s.rid
  SET  sku = 'updatedSKU'
  WHERE s.rn > 1;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef615/1)**

Comment: Tried but it is not updating any of the record. the query just executed and nothing happends

Comment: thanks thanks alot dear it is working perfectly fine just tested and achieved the correct result as required. You are really great :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rid is unique this version works without relying on the order of the data.

```
update skus, (
       select id, min(rid) rid from skus group by id 
) minimum_rid
set skus.sku = 'updated'
, skus.name = 'updated'
where skus.id = minimum_rid.id
and skus.rid > minimum_rid.rid ;
```